# How can you ensure a feedcomment trigger only applies for cases?

Tags: trigger, feedcomment

I apologize if this is turns out to be ridiculously easy.

I've managed to configure a **feedcomment trigger** that behaves as desired except for a big point:
we need it to either:
- Only apply within Salesforce **cases**
- Only apply within a specifc **layout**

So, in short, I'm only missing an **IF**, whose syntax I cannot figure out due to a total lack of experience with available Apex methods/calls/etc.

If anyone could share either a sample of related advice, it would be tremendously appreciated as I've been scouring the web for the better part of the last two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any SObject ID can return the type of the SObject it references via the [getSObjectType()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm#apex_System_Id_getSObjectType) method. So this approach (I haven't tried it) should achieve your first filter of limiting the trigger to only act on `Case` feed comments:

```
for (FeedComment cd : Trigger.new) {
    if (cd.FeedItemId.getSObjectType() == CaseFeedItem.SObjectType) {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

Page layouts are identified using the combination of record type and `User` profile. Assuming you have no record types defined for your `Case` objects, then the user's profile can be found using the [UserInfo.getProfileId()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getProfileId) method and converted into a profile name by then querying the `Profile` object. So further if/else logic based on the profile ID or name can be added to the above code.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me, Keith. Your answer pointed me in the right direction.  
I finally got my IF to work by doing the following, in case it can help someone who stumbles here.  
////////////////////  
if((fc.CommentType== 'TextComment' || fc.CommentType== 'ContentComment') && (fc.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType))
////////////////////

Comment: @JFGirard Yeah yours looks better - I didn't check what the ParentId was.